# Why does Twitter give different search results for the same keyword search (sorted by latest) when searching from 2 different accounts?

Tags: twitter, tweet, twitter-search

I type in a keyword and sort the stream for "latest". I performed that same search on 2 different Twitter accounts but get different search results of those real time tweets. Why? Is it a Twitter bug?